# Python ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Token'

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

Here is the structure of my compiler program:

```
|mainProject
|--Parser
|-----__init__.py
|-----Parser.py
|-----parser_test.py
|--Tokenizer
|-----__init__.py
|-----Tokenizer.py
|-----Token.py
```

In the tokenizer.py, I have

```
   from Token import *
```

which passes all tokenizer test I have.

Then in the parser.py I have

```
    from Tokenizer.Tokenizer import Tokenizer
```

In the parser_test.py I have

```
    from Parser import Parser
```

> So basically, Tokenizer uses Token, now Parser need to import Tokenizer but cannot find Token module

when I run the test for parser, I get Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mainproject/Parser/parse_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Parser import Parser
  File "mainproject/Parser/Parser.py", line 3, in <module>
    from Tokenizer.Tokenizer import Tokenizer
  File "mainproject/Tokenizer/Tokenizer.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Token import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Token'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok So I finally figured out how to solve the problem.
If a import b, b import c, and b, c is in the same package
the correct way is to use absolute path in a when import b
and in b you need to use relative path to import c.
So, in my case:
in the parser.py I should have:

```
from Tokenizer.Tokenizer import Tokenizer
```

and in the Tokenizer.py I should have:

```
from .Token import Token
```

The `.` in the above line shows Tokenizer is importing a module from the same package.